# SQL Exclude Field from GROUP BY in results but use in WHERE

Tags: t-sql

Pretty simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Recognitions](
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Submitter_CH_id] [int] NULL,
[Submitter_Last_Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Submit_Date] [datetime] NULL,

Submitter_CH_id Submitter_Last_Name Submit_Date
50              Prokupek             2014-04-01 00:00:00.000
50              Prokupek             2014-04-07 00:00:00.000
50              Prokupek             2014-04-01 00:00:00.000
50              Prokupek             2014-04-07 00:00:00.000
215             Conklin              2014-04-07 00:00:00.000
215             Conklin              2014-04-07 00:00:00.000
130             Catron               2014-04-07 00:00:00.000
136             Jardee               2014-04-07 00:00:00.000
247             Emken                2014-04-07 00:00:00.000
```

What I need to do is get a count of all the submissions made with in a certain date range grouped by `recipient_ch_id`.  My app allows the user to enter the date range, so it needs to be part of the query results for my app to use it.

I need the results to be grouped by `Submitter_CH_id`.  So something like this:

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT Submitter_CH_id, Submitter_First_Name, Submitter_Last_Name,     Submitter_Email, Submitter_Department, 
                  Submit_Date AS [Last Submit], COUNT(Submitter_CH_id) AS [Total Submit]
FROM         dbo.Recognitions
GROUP BY Submitter_First_Name, Submitter_Last_Name, Submitter_Email,     Submitter_Department, Submitter_CH_id, Submit_Date
ORDER BY Submitter_CH_id
```

What I would like is the following:

```
Submitter_CH_ID Submitter_Last_Name Total Submissions
50              Prokupek             4
215             Conklin              2
130             Catron               1
```

... but because I also have to include `Submit_Date` in my `GROUP BY` the results instead show the count per ID per unique date (which it has to of course), so I get something like this:

```
Submitter_CH_ID Submitter_Last_Name Total Submissions
50              Prokupek                 2
50              Prokupek                 2
215             Conklin              1
215             Conklin              1
130             Catron               1
```

Any thoughts?  This is MS SQL 2008.  Thanks very much.

Comment: What is `recipient_ch_id`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use a sub query.... like this:

```
select Submitter_CH_ID, Submitter_Last_Name, count(ID) AS [Total Submissions]
from (
    select ID, Submitter_CH_ID, Submitter_Last_Name
    from  dbo.Recognitions
    where date >= @start_date and date <= @end_date
) T
GROUP BY Submitter_CH_ID, Submitter_Last_Name
```

yay sub-queries!

Comment: Ahhh, this is exactly what I had but the app I'm using to generate the ASP code won't "see" @parameters.  In any case, I will probably just write this one particular report by hand.

Comment: I have no idea what that means "won't see @parameters"... but I'm sure it is different than the question you asked.  Maybe ask another question?

Comment: It's a little hard to explain, and don't get me wrong this code will work perfectly if I write the asp page myself.  I'm using ASPMaker, which will read the views in SQL Server and build out add/edit/search etc.  ASPMaker will look at the select statement and build accordingly.  If the date is not in the select, aspmaker will not create a field for it - that sorta make sense?  So the user would have no where to enter the dates.  If i make the pages, I can put the fields in myself.  In any case, thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you feel that you need `Submit_Date` in the `GROUP BY` clause because you're including it in the `SELECT` clause, because you're filtering by this value in the returned results.  If that's correct, you can delete the field from your `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` lists if you instead filter in this query:

```
SELECT
    Submitter_CH_ID, Submitter_Last_Name, COUNT(*) AS Submissions
FROM
    Recognitions
WHERE
    Submit_Date BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
GROUP BY
    Submitter_CH_ID, Submitter_Last_Name
ORDER BY
    Submitter_CH_ID
```