# Aggregated Function with LAST_VALUE using CASE Statement and GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, merge, sql-server-2012

I am using a `MERGE` statement, int the `SELECT` query I am trying to use the `LAST_VALUE` function inside a `CASE` statement with different summary types (e.g. SUM, AVG, etc.) with aggregated functions. I want to exclude `[Value]`, `[Target]` and `[Budget]` fields from the `GROUP BY` clause. I am using `OVER ORDER BY` syntax but keep getting the following error:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
>   Column '@TempFact_KPI.Value' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

CODE:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[TempFact_KPI] AS TABLE(
[PeriodKey] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
[KPIKey] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
[SummaryType] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[PeriodDateTime] [datetime] NULL,
[Value] [real] NULL,
[Target] [real] NULL,
[Budget] [real] NULL
)
GO
```

Stored procedure:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    [PeriodKey],
    [KPIKey],
    CASE [SummaryType]
       WHEN 'Sum' THEN SUM([Value])
       WHEN 'Count' THEN COUNT([Value])
       WHEN 'Mean' THEN AVG([Value])
       WHEN 'Maximum' THEN MAX([Value])
       WHEN 'Minimum' THEN MIN([Value])
       WHEN 'Last' THEN LAST_VALUE([Value]) OVER (ORDER BY [PeriodDateTime] ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
       ELSE [Value]
    END as [Value],
    CASE [SummaryType]
       WHEN 'Sum' THEN SUM([Target])
       WHEN 'Count' THEN COUNT([Target])
       WHEN 'Mean' THEN AVG([Target])
       WHEN 'Maximum' THEN MAX([Target])
       WHEN 'Minimum' THEN MIN([Target])
       WHEN 'Last' THEN LAST_VALUE([Target]) OVER (ORDER BY [PeriodDateTime] ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
       ELSE [Target]
    END AS [Target],
    CASE [SummaryType]
       WHEN 'Sum' THEN SUM([Budget])
       WHEN 'Count' THEN COUNT([Budget])
       WHEN 'Mean' THEN AVG([Budget])
       WHEN 'Maximum' THEN MAX([Budget])
       WHEN 'Minimum' THEN MIN([Budget])
       WHEN 'Last' THEN LAST_VALUE([Budget]) OVER (ORDER BY [PeriodDateTime] ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
       ELSE [Budget]
    END AS [Budget] 
FROM 
    @TempFact_KPI
GROUP BY 
    [PeriodKey], [KPIKey], [SummaryType]
```

I have looked at the suggestions posted [Query for Min, Max, Avg, and Last Value in TSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48544339/query-for-min-max-avg-and-last-value-in-tsql) and [SQL Exclude Field from GROUP BY in results but use in WHERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22923032/sql-exclude-field-from-group-by-in-results-but-use-in-where#), but it still not providing the wanted results

Comment: When grouping, all fields must either be part of the GROUP BY clause or part of an aggregate.  That's a logical requirement, there's no way around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use windowed functions:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
[PeriodKey]
,[KPIKey]
,CASE [SummaryType]
    WHEN 'Sum'     THEN SUM([Value])   OVER(PARTITION BY [PeriodKey], [KPIKey], [SummaryType])
    WHEN 'Count'   THEN COUNT([Value]) OVER(PARTITION BY [PeriodKey], [KPIKey], [SummaryType])
    WHEN 'Mean'    THEN AVG([Value])   OVER(PARTITION BY [PeriodKey], [KPIKey], [SummaryType])
    WHEN 'Maximum' THEN MAX([Value])   OVER(PARTITION BY [PeriodKey], [KPIKey], [SummaryType])
    WHEN 'Minimum' THEN MIN([Value])   OVER(PARTITION BY [PeriodKey], [KPIKey], [SummaryType])
    WHEN 'Last'    THEN LAST_VALUE([Value]) OVER (PARTITION BY [PeriodKey], [KPIKey], [SummaryType] ORDER BY [PeriodDateTime] ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
    ELSE [Value]
END as [Value]
 -- ...
FROM @TempFact_KPI;
```

Comment: Isn't this is effectively the same as adding [Value],[Target], and [Budget] to the GROUP by clause in OPs query?

Comment: There is still an error Column '@TempFact_KPI.PeriodKey' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: If I add the GROUP BY [PeriodKey], [KPIKey], [SummaryType], I still get the same error I mentioned "Column '@TempFact_KPI.Value' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Comment: @WayneHollier The **whole** point of windowed function was that there won't be any GROUP BY. Please read carefully after `FROM @TempFact_KPI;` there is end of query.

Comment: Thanks for the help.